# Separate comma delimited text file to array

Tags: java, arrays, separator

I have a text file with multiple lines, and 3 comma delimited entries per line.

Example:

> Soviet Union,Larisa_LATYNINA,18
>   United States,Michael_PHELPS,16
>   Soviet Union,Nikolay_ANDRIANOV,15

I'm trying to separate them into 3 arrays, with 1 for the country, 1 for the person, and 1 for the medals.

```
        ArrayList<String> country = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> medals = new ArrayList<>();
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("Olympics.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        input.useDelimiter(" , ");
        while(input.hasNext()) {
            country.add(input.next());
            name.add(input.next());
            medals.add(input.nextInt());
        }
```

but I get a error every time I try to run it. I'm not exactly sure how to separate each "column" in the file into their own array.

If I use `useDelimiter(",");` instead of `useDelimiter(" , ");` I am getting the follow exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
at OlympicWinners.main(OlympicWinners.java:14)
```

This is the error I get. Line 14 is

```
Medals.add(input.nextInt());
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] (especially the error, the expected and current output).

Comment: Please stick to naming conventions, variable names always lowerCase. So `country`, `name`, `medals`.

Comment: Note that you might also want to read by lines and then split by comma. Else you might switch into the next line without noticing, for bad input. Something along: `List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("Olympics.txt"))`. And then `String[] data = line.split(",");`.

Comment: And just for the record: A) writing your own CSV parser logic is a good exercise, but in the real world you better use one of the many existing libraries for it. You are re-inventing the wheel here (repeating all the mistakes that other people made in the past) B) be careful about putting that information into 3 different lists, and "connecting" them via an **index**. Rather consider to create a class that models one ROW in your file, like a "MedalWinner". That class would have three fields (for nation, name, count). And then you put one object of that class in a single list. Your idea of

Comment: using three lists to represent data that belongs together in **one** object is the exact opposite of how you approach such tasks in good OOP.

Answer (score 1):

From your text sample, the delimiter isn't a comma surrounded with spaces (`" , "`), but just a comma (`","`). Remove those spaces and you should be OK:

```
input.useDelimiter(",");
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to fix the problem. This is what I get:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
 at OlympicWinners.main(OlympicWinners.java:14)

Comment: @BenjaminWu It is impossible to fix your issue. We can only guess right now. Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `InputMismatchException` because of the last line `input.nextInt()` returns

```
"18 
United States"
```

Since there is no `,` delimiter between `18` and `United States` (but there is line separator `\n`) each token is returned from delimiter to delimiter.

You should read all lines from file and split them by separator:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("Olympic.txt"));

for (String line : lines) {
    String[] fields = line.split(",");
    country.add(fields[0]);
    name.add(fields[1]);
    medals.add(Integer.valueOf(fields[2]));
}
```

Comment: Tried your solution, but I get
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
 at OlympicWinners.main(OlympicWinners.java:14)
and line 14 is 

name.add(fields[1]);

Comment: @BenjaminWu make sure that in your txt file each line has exactly 3 fields

Comment: Would countries with spaces in between (e.g. United States) affect this?

Comment: @BenjaminWu No. There is specified delimiter `.split(",")`. Spaces are ignored

Comment: @BenjaminWu `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1` is showing up most probably because one of the lines from txt file has only country value. But doesn't have name and medal

Comment: I think I got it, there was a space at the end of the text file.

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your code to this :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<String> country = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> medals = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader reader;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("F://test.txt"));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                String[] lineParts = line.split(",");
                country.add(lineParts[0]);
                name.add(lineParts[1]); 
                medals.add(Integer.valueOf(lineParts[2]));
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(country);
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(medals);

    }

}
```

In test.xml :

```
Soviet Union,Larisa_LATYNINA,18
United States,Michael_PHELPS,16
Soviet Union,Nikolay_ANDRIANOV,15
```

Output of the code :

```
[Soviet Union, United States, Soviet Union]
[Larisa_LATYNINA, Michael_PHELPS, Nikolay_ANDRIANOV]
[18, 16, 15]
```